# NextJS 13 +next-auth SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression

Tags: next.js, next-auth

When I run `npm run dev` command I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^/_next/data/development/api/auth/[...nextauth}.json$/: Unterminated character class at new RegExp (<anonymous>) at buildDataRoute (/home/plamen/Code/promptopia/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/build-data-route.js:34:69) at Watchpack.<anonymous> (/home/plamen/Code/promptopia/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev.js:875:70)
```

The full code repo is here:https://github.com/plamen5rov/promptopia/tree/master

Most of the code is created 1:1 as in the original repo here: https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_next_13_ai_prompt_sharing/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the bother! Found the answer myself:

the directory was named `[...naxtauth}` instead of `[...naxtauth]`